# extjs-showing records in a grid from two different stores?

Tags: extjs

Hi i have a grid and i have two stores and i want to display both the store data in the same grid is there a way to do it...help please

Comment: dou you mean you have 2 store with same structure ?? it's a waste thing. assuming U use Extjs 3.*.* take look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405437/how-to-add-records-in-json-store. this show you how to add new record..

Comment: Definitely curious why you are using two stores.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (without some gnarly hacking) show two stores in a grid.

What you can do is make a third store which listens to two child stores for add/datachanged/update/remove events. Take a look [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/#Ext.data.Store-events) for what you'll need to support.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the first data col comes from Store 1 and the data from Store 2 forms cols 2 and 3. You can use a renderer that finds the data in the second store if the 'other' columns are just 'lookup' data, e.g.:

```
var store1 = new Ext.data.Store({
    ...,
    fields: ['field1', 'field2']
});

var store2 = new Ext.data.Store({
    ...
    id: 'field2',
    fields: ['field2', 'fieldA', 'fieldB']
});

var renderA = function(value) {
    var rec = store2.getById(value);
    return rec ? rec.get('fieldA') : '';
}
var renderB = function(value) {
    var rec = store2.getById(value);
    return rec ? rec.get('fieldB') : '';
}

var columns = [
    {header: 'Field 1', dataIndex: 'field1'},
    {header: 'Field A', dataIndex: 'field2', renderer: renderA},
    {header: 'Field B', dataIndex: 'field2', renderer: renderB}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The more renderers you use, the slower things will render as it's doing quite a lot, think how many renderers you have then.... 10 columns, 100 rows... 10 X 100 = 1,000 renderers.

Think how to fix your problem then to deal with what you have.