# ExtJS creating record from existing store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created an ext store like so:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
       root: 'vars',
       fields: [{ name: 'rec_id', mapping: 'rec' }, { name: 'identity', mapping: 'id'}]
});
```

This works alright when I add data to the store via `loadData();` and some json which looks like:

```
{ vars : {rec: '1', id:'John'} }
```

My problem is that if I use `add();` to get this record into the store I have to first create it as an `Ext.data.Record` object.

I do this as pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828701/1749630 and it works ok.

The issue I have is that the records are entered with their mapped parameters rather than the ones I set. I.e, 'rec_id' becomes 'rec' and 'identity' becomes 'id'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the mapping manually, something like this:

```
var myNewRecord = new store.recordType({
    rec_id: vars.rec,
    identity: vars.id
});

store.add(myNewRecord);
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I believe in ExtJS4 this is now `store.model(...)`